# Can't change the image when mouse enters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the image when the mouse enters and change back when mouse leaves. I couldn't handle that for hours. Please help :)

I want to change "yazilogo2.png" with "yazilogo_active.png".

Here is my code:

```
<style>

    #topContainer {
        background-image:url("yaziylabin_header1.png");
        width:100%;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center;
        margin-top:51px;
    }

    .logo {
        height:80px;
    }

    .logoDiv {
        margin-top:15px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container contentContainer" style="padding-top:70px;" id="topContainer">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 logoDiv">
                <img class="logo center-block" src="yazilogo2.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(".contentContainer").css("min-height", 0.55*($(window).height()));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at [DOM Event Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) with an [exampe](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseenter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the src attribute of image element to change the image. You can use hover() method of jQuery for mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
$('.logo').hover(
  // function for mouseenter
  function () { $(this).attr("src", "yazilogo_active.png");},
  // function for mouseleave
  function () {$(this).attr("src", "yazilogo2.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".logo").hover(
function(){
    $(this).attr("src","pic1.png");
},
function(){
    $(this).attr("src","pic2.png");
});
```

You can find out about . hover() [here.](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)